# D operators that are not in C++

Tags: c++, d

Are there any operators in D that are not in C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a list of some D tokens

```
/=
.
..
...
&
&=
&&
|
|=
||
-
-=
--
+
+=
++
<
<=
<<
<<=
<>
<>=
>
>=
>>=
>>>=
>>
>>>
!
!=
!<>
!<>=
!<
!<=
!>
!>=
(
)
[
]
{
}
?
,
;
:
$
=
==
*
*=
%
%=
^
^=
~
~=
```

Those for example:

```
<>
<>=
!<>
!<>=
!<
!<=
!>
!>=
```

are special operators to compare floating point variables. You can find the description of them here http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/expression.html

There are also the

```
is 
!is
in
!in
typeof
```

operators.

Comment: Super, thats a great list. Thanks.

Comment: Walter Bright said that the floating-point comparisons with NaN support (!<> !<>= !< !<= !> !>=) will be deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

- `^^` and `^^=` for exponentiation
- `~` and `~=` for concatenation
- `>>>` and `>>>=` for signed (or is it unsigned) bit shift

Comment: D has exponentiation? Wasn't ^ xor?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't program D in a long time, but I think it has `opApply` for use in `foreach` - I don't know if you count it as an operator, but it sure is documented as such :)

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Sadface's opApply there is also opCall for overloading when () is used, useful in structs. In fact on the [Operator Overloading](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/operatoroverloading.html) page there is a number of these:

```
opIndex
opIndexAssign
opSlice
opSliceAssign
opDispatch -- Rather interesting addition in D2
```

Comment: opDispatch is amazing.  It's like overloading the '.' operator is c++.